# Constraint the number of rows returned by JOIN FETCH in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm having a Product object with a list of related products (which are also product objects). The field of related products is annotated like this:

```
 public class Product {

    @JoinTable(name = "RELATED_PRODUCT", joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "RELATED_PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Product> relatedProducts;
 }
```

As you can see the list is fetched lazy, which is what I want in most cases. In some cases however, I want the list of related products to be filled immediatly. I created a query for this with a LEFT JOIN FETCH. However, I want only the related products to be added that have a certain rating, let's say a rating of > 3.

I tried the following:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.comparableProducts cp WHERE p.id = :id AND cp.rating > 3 AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN p.commenceDate AND p.removeDate
```

But this doesn't work. It always returns back ALL related products in the database, not just the ones that have a rating above 3. How is this fixable?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to load related products separately instead of trying to fit them into `relatedProducts` field.

It also makes perfect sense from object oriented point of view. I suppose you have something like "Product page" that contains the selected product and "recommended products". If so, such a page is a separate concept that deserves its own class:

```
public class ProductPage {
    private Product product;
    private List<Product> recommendedProducts;
    ...
}
```

Then you can fill such a class either by a single query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p, cp FROM Product p LEFT JOIN p.comparableProducts cp WHERE p.id = :id AND cp.rating > 3 AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN p.commenceDate AND p.removeDate
```

or by two separate queries.

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't allow you to receive an instance of `ProductPage` directly from JPA, you need to write conversion code manually.

Comment: Hmm... a bit of a flaw that JPA can't do this or am I wrong here? I suppose it wouldn't be too difficult to just add the product objects to the list that have a rating > 3. After all, such a mechanism can be used without the fetch (ie: I could fetch for 'original' product's that have a rating > 3 easily) and is also part of SQL. I believe you when you say your answer is the solution to my question, but this seems cumbersome. All I want is a product that contains related products. They are PART OF that perticular product, so they should belong to it, even from an object oriented point of view..

Comment: The point is that it goes agains the spirit of JPA in some sense, because JPA assumes that state of persistent fields reflects the state of the database.

Comment: Yeah I agree on that, but my situation seems like one any programmer can be in. Just a typical relationship issue. I really thought there would be a nice and clean way of doing this, but unfortunatly there isn't. It seems I just have to accept that. Thanks for the answer anyway!